# Samba configuration, status[NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED],

Tags: linux, linux-networking, centos7, samba

I am trying to configure samba with centos7 to be accessed from windows 10 clients.

**log level = 1** i used a previously working smb.conf from the same server after reinstalling centos.

**log level = 10** 
you can actually skip reading this, its level 10 details.

**start**

i am very new to configuring a linux server, i am familiar with basic linux command `ls` `chmod` `chown` `...`,

i followed [this article](http://www.krizna.com/centos/setup-file-server-centos-7/) to configure a secure share on wlan network and then tested it with a colleague, everything was working ok except that he did not have execution permission on the share, the path is `/home/CompanyFiles/All`

so i executed `cd /home/`

then `chmod -R 777 /`

then i successfully changed the permissions of the entire centos files and broke the centos installation.

after some googling i decided that reinstalling centos is better than trying to recover from the chmod command and it was feasible since i only installed samba on it, so i copied smb.conf to another machine, reinstalled centos and reinstalled samba, and then i used the old smb.conf.

**end**

smb.conf:

```
[global]
        workgroup = WORKGROUP
        security = user
        map to guest = Bad User
        printing = cups
        printcap name = cups
        load printers = yes
        cups options = raw
        log level = 4
        #ntlm auth = yes
        passdb backend = tdbsam
        netbios name = adServer

[homes]
        comment = Home Directories
        valid users = %S, %D%w%S
        browsable = No
        read only = No
        inherit acls = Yes
[CompanyFiles]
        path = /home/CompanyFiles
        guest ok = yes
        browsable = no
        writable = yes

[All]
        comment = Company Access
        path = /home/CompanyFiles/All
        guest ok = no
        browsable = yes
        writable = yes
        #access based share enum = yes
```

the permission of the folders are:

`drwxrwx--x. 3 everyad  adusers 17 Feb 26 09:32 CompanyFiles`

`drwxrwx--x. 2 everyad adusers 42 Feb 26 11:43 All`

where all users are members of the group adusers.

also the users trying to access are created on smb using `smbpasswd -a username`

BUT i get the following error when trying to access the server from windows 10

> you do not have permission to access server ...

please not that i removed samba and reinstalled it with no success.

when making the log level 4 i receive `status[NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED]`, but with lower level i don't get an error.

```
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.480678,  4] ../source3/smbd/uid.c:384(change_to_user)
  Skipping user change - already user
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.480788,  4] ../source3/smbd/vfs.c:874(vfs_ChDir)
  vfs_ChDir to /home/CompanyFiles/All
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.480835,  4] ../source3/smbd/vfs.c:874(vfs_ChDir)
  vfs_ChDir to /home/CompanyFiles/All
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.480864,  3] ../source3/smbd/service.c:102(set_current_service)
  chdir (/home/CompanyFiles/All) failed, reason: Permission denied
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.480913,  3] ../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:3097(smbd_smb2_request_error_ex)
  smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: idx[1] status[NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED] || at ../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:2449
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.481098,  4] ../source3/smbd/uid.c:384(change_to_user)
  Skipping user change - already user
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.481145,  4] ../source3/smbd/vfs.c:874(vfs_ChDir)
  vfs_ChDir to /home/CompanyFiles/All
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.481172,  4] ../source3/smbd/vfs.c:874(vfs_ChDir)
  vfs_ChDir to /home/CompanyFiles/All
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.481202,  3] ../source3/smbd/service.c:102(set_current_service)
  chdir (/home/CompanyFiles/All) failed, reason: Permission denied
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.481244,  3] ../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:3097(smbd_smb2_request_error_ex)
  smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: idx[1] status[NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED] || at ../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:2449
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.481407,  4] ../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:321(set_sec_ctx_internal)
  setting sec ctx (1006, 1014) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.481671,  4] ../source3/rpc_server/rpc_ncacn_np.c:89(make_internal_rpc_pipe_socketpair)
  Create of internal pipe srvsvc requested
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.485044,  4] ../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:321(set_sec_ctx_internal)
  setting sec ctx (1006, 1014) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.485191,  4] ../source3/smbd/vfs.c:874(vfs_ChDir)
  vfs_ChDir to /home/CompanyFiles/All
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.485232,  4] ../source3/smbd/vfs.c:874(vfs_ChDir)
  vfs_ChDir to /home/CompanyFiles/All
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.485286,  3] ../source3/smbd/service.c:102(set_current_service)
  chdir (/home/CompanyFiles/All) failed, reason: Permission denied
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.485387,  3] ../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:3097(smbd_smb2_request_error_ex)
  smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: idx[1] status[NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED] || at ../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:2449
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.485519,  4] ../source3/smbd/uid.c:384(change_to_user)
  Skipping user change - already user
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.485564,  4] ../source3/smbd/vfs.c:874(vfs_ChDir)
  vfs_ChDir to /home/CompanyFiles/All
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.485593,  4] ../source3/smbd/vfs.c:874(vfs_ChDir)
  vfs_ChDir to /home/CompanyFiles/All
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.485617,  3] ../source3/smbd/service.c:102(set_current_service)
  chdir (/home/CompanyFiles/All) failed, reason: Permission denied
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.485662,  3] ../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:3097(smbd_smb2_request_error_ex)
  smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: idx[1] status[NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED] || at ../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:2449
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.486887,  4] ../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:321(set_sec_ctx_internal)
  setting sec ctx (1006, 1014) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.647037,  4] ../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:321(set_sec_ctx_internal)
  setting sec ctx (1006, 1014) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.647199,  4] ../source3/smbd/vfs.c:874(vfs_ChDir)
  vfs_ChDir to /home/CompanyFiles/All
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.647244,  4] ../source3/smbd/vfs.c:874(vfs_ChDir)
  vfs_ChDir to /home/CompanyFiles/All
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.647280,  3] ../source3/smbd/service.c:102(set_current_service)
  chdir (/home/CompanyFiles/All) failed, reason: Permission denied
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.647399,  3] ../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:3097(smbd_smb2_request_error_ex)
  smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: idx[1] status[NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED] || at ../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:2449
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.647849,  4] ../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:321(set_sec_ctx_internal)
  setting sec ctx (1006, 1014) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.648141,  3] ../source3/rpc_server/srv_pipe.c:732(api_pipe_bind_req)
  api_pipe_bind_req: srvsvc -> srvsvc rpc service
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.648192,  3] ../source3/rpc_server/srv_pipe.c:355(check_bind_req)
  check_bind_req for srvsvc context_id=0
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.648242,  3] ../source3/rpc_server/srv_pipe.c:398(check_bind_req)
  check_bind_req: srvsvc -> srvsvc rpc service
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.762983,  4] ../source3/smbd/uid.c:384(change_to_user)
  Skipping user change - already user
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.807647,  4] ../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:321(set_sec_ctx_internal)
  setting sec ctx (1006, 1014) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.807736,  4] ../source3/smbd/vfs.c:874(vfs_ChDir)
  vfs_ChDir to /home/CompanyFiles/All
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.807758,  4] ../source3/smbd/vfs.c:874(vfs_ChDir)
  vfs_ChDir to /home/CompanyFiles/All
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.807777,  3] ../source3/smbd/service.c:102(set_current_service)
  chdir (/home/CompanyFiles/All) failed, reason: Permission denied
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.807808,  3] ../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:3097(smbd_smb2_request_error_ex)
  smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: idx[1] status[NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED] || at ../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:2449
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.816357,  4] ../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:321(set_sec_ctx_internal)
  setting sec ctx (1006, 1014) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.816537,  4] ../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:217(push_sec_ctx)
  push_sec_ctx(1006, 1014) : sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.816566,  4] ../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:321(set_sec_ctx_internal)
  setting sec ctx (1006, 1014) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.816606,  4] ../source3/rpc_server/srv_pipe.c:1434(api_rpcTNP)
  api_rpcTNP: srvsvc op 0x10 - api_rpcTNP: rpc command: SRVSVC_NETSHAREGETINFO
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.816664,  4] ../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:439(pop_sec_ctx)
  pop_sec_ctx (1006, 1014) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.845244,  4] ../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:321(set_sec_ctx_internal)
  setting sec ctx (1006, 1014) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.845361,  4] ../source3/smbd/vfs.c:874(vfs_ChDir)
  vfs_ChDir to /home/CompanyFiles/All
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.845381,  4] ../source3/smbd/vfs.c:874(vfs_ChDir)
  vfs_ChDir to /home/CompanyFiles/All
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.845393,  3] ../source3/smbd/service.c:102(set_current_service)
  chdir (/home/CompanyFiles/All) failed, reason: Permission denied
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.845409,  3] ../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:3097(smbd_smb2_request_error_ex)
  smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: idx[1] status[NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED] || at ../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:2449
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.845461,  4] ../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:321(set_sec_ctx_internal)
  setting sec ctx (1006, 1014) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.859382,  4] ../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:321(set_sec_ctx_internal)
  setting sec ctx (1006, 1014) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.859442,  4] ../source3/smbd/vfs.c:874(vfs_ChDir)
  vfs_ChDir to /home/CompanyFiles/All
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.859458,  4] ../source3/smbd/vfs.c:874(vfs_ChDir)
  vfs_ChDir to /home/CompanyFiles/All
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.859467,  3] ../source3/smbd/service.c:102(set_current_service)
  chdir (/home/CompanyFiles/All) failed, reason: Permission denied
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.859482,  3] ../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:3097(smbd_smb2_request_error_ex)
  smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: idx[1] status[NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED] || at ../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:2449
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.859547,  4] ../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:321(set_sec_ctx_internal)
  setting sec ctx (1006, 1014) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2018/03/07 12:16:46.859580,  3] ../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:3097(smbd_smb2_request_error_ex)
  smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: idx[1] status[NT_STATUS_FS_DRIVER_REQUIRED] || at ../source3/smbd/smb2_ioctl.c:309
[2018/03/07 12:16:48.603901,  4] ../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:321(set_sec_ctx_internal)
  setting sec ctx (1006, 1014) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2018/03/07 12:16:48.604057,  4] ../source3/smbd/vfs.c:874(vfs_ChDir)
  vfs_ChDir to /home/CompanyFiles/All
[2018/03/07 12:16:48.604105,  4] ../source3/smbd/vfs.c:874(vfs_ChDir)
  vfs_ChDir to /home/CompanyFiles/All
[2018/03/07 12:16:48.604171,  3] ../source3/smbd/service.c:102(set_current_service)
  chdir (/home/CompanyFiles/All) failed, reason: Permission denied
[2018/03/07 12:16:48.604228,  3] ../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:3097(smbd_smb2_request_error_ex)
  smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: idx[1] status[NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED] || at ../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c
```

searching online always led to selinux stuff, firewall or permissions:

selinux is permissive

firewalld is disabled

and still getting the same issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I FINALLY managed to solve this problem.

first of all i removed the existing connections from windows 10 using `net use * /delete` from the command line since the credentials where saved and i changed them on the server

also for some reason i had to specify `smbpasswd` in /etc/samba/smb.conf: `passdb backend = smbpasswd` in the `[global]` section

also the /home permission where wrong and all my shares are in /home so i reset the permission to 755: `chmod -R 755 /home`

then i reset all the shares permission and group access based on my needs.

Answer (score 2):

We had the [NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED] error where users could access their HOME shares but not any other shares.

> /var/log/samba/__ffff_172.16.0.35.log:
>
> [2019/03/05 11:26:53.914706,  1] smbd/service.c:678(make_connection_snum)
>     create_connection_server_info failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED

This was caused by Domain Controllers being restarted whilst SAMBA and WINBIND servers were running. Simply restarting services winbind & smb resolved the issue.

A light fix; but worth a mention

Answer (score 1):

This just happened to me as well, with the latest Samba on Fedora. I was mysteriously getting 'access denied' responses when trying to create/write/delete files and folders in sub-directories of my Samba share from Windows. Weirdly, changing files in the root folder worked fine.

I changed the setting from `passdb backend = tdbsam` to `passdb backend = smbpasswd`, ran `smbpasswd -a myuser` to re-add my user and password, and restarted the smb service. This fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Do not forget to do `net use * /delete` as windows seems to keep some invalid data in its cache. This makes my smbd suddently accepting my password.

Answer (score 0):

Apparmor might also be the cause. You need to whitelist all share locations, otherwise you will always get the "permission denied" error.

Fix is adding to `/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.smbd`:

```
"/path_to_share/" rk,
"/path_to_share/**" lrwk,
```

for each share. (The first line allows read-access to the base-directory, the second line allows read-write-access to everything within that base-directory recursively)

Source: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Samba#Permission_issues_on_AppArmor